# How to serialize a class with Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject to change empty List to null variable

Tags: json, json.net, jsonconvert

How to serialize a class `with Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject`  to change empty List to null variable

my result from serialization

```
{"images":[]} or {"images":{}}
```

and would like to get

```
{"images":null}
```

my simple class

```
public class Images
{
[JsonProperty("images", Required = Required.Always, NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include)]

   public Images()
   {
   Parameters = new Parameters(); **//  I know I could not initiate here only when I need it but I don't want to do it**
   }

   [JsonProperty("parameters", Required = Required.Always, NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include)]
   public Parameters Parameters { get; set; }
}

public class Parameters 
{
   [JsonProperty("id", Required = Required.AllowNull, NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include)]
   public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: *my class is too long and I don't know how to add it here* -- then don't.  Instead add a **minimal** class that demonstrates your problem -- i.e. a [mcve].  Probably just `public class MyClass { public List<byte []> images { get; set; } }` would be enough

Comment: Also, why are you getting `{"images":{}}`?  You state you have an *empty list* but `{}` will never get generated for a `List<T>`; only a JSON array -- delimited by `[` and `]` -- will get created when serializing a list.

Comment: What are you trying to serialize?

Comment: zaktualizowałem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something like that

```
           internal class NullEmptyConverter : JsonConverter
        {
            public override bool CanConvert(Type t) => t == typeof(GuidId);
            public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type t, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
            {
                if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null) return null;
                var value = serializer.Deserialize<string>(reader);
                return value;
            }
            public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object untypedValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
            {
                if (JsonConvert.SerializeObject(untypedValue, Formatting.None).ToString() == "[]")
                {
                    serializer.Serialize(writer, null);
                    return;
                }

                if (JsonConvert.SerializeObject(untypedValue, Formatting.None).ToString() == "{}")
                {
                    serializer.Serialize(writer, null);
                    return;
                }

                serializer.Serialize(writer,untypedValue);
                return;
            }
        }
```

use

```
 [JsonConverter (typeof (NullEmptyConverter))]
```

immediately before

```
public Parameters Parameters { get; set; }
```

It works, but maybe it can be done better, simpler or somewhere else something is wrong here?